# Performing a postgresql query using Node.js but using a variable to query with parameter

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am creating a script using node that will grab records created in the last half an hour from a PostgreSQL database. I have:

```js
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at>'2015-9-16 20:04:17'");
```

Now, my issue is that I want the `created_at>'2015-9-16 20:04:17'` to actually search for records created in the last half hour using a variable I have called `time`. The variable time is set to the last half hour:

```js
var currentdate = new Date();
var diff=30;
var time = new Date(currentdate.getTime() - diff*60000);
var day=time.getDate();
var month=time.getMonth()+1;
var year=time.getFullYear();
var hours=time.getHours();
var minutes=time.getMinutes();
var seconds=time.getSeconds();

var time=year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
```

How do I change the query so that it searches for `date>time`?  Originally I thought I could write:

```js
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at>'$time'");
```

Comment: Your question isn't relevant to Node JS, it's a pure PostgreSQL syntax thing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I suggest you to do:

```
var time=year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at >'" + time + "'");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid all the calculation on the client side, and instead compute the required start-time in SQL:

```js
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM users "
                         + "WHERE created_at > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTES)");
```

(I split the string purely for readability here; you don't need to do the same)